# Calculation of random variable probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have a question about how to solve this exercise: The monthly sales of a certain consumables store are distributed evenly, with average 4000e and standard deviation 1200e, and the estimated expenses for the same period amount to 4200e.

1-Let X be the random variable number of months with losses in the next semester (6 months). Determine its probability function.

2-What is the probability that in the next semester you will have losses in at least three months?

Here, first of all I have calculated a uniform distribution U (a, b). As the mean and typical deviation indicate, I calculate the values that take a and b with the formulas and they give me [a = 6078.460969  b = 1921.539030, a = 1921.539030  b = 6078.460969].

As a < b , I throw away the first option and I'll take the second one. Once arrived at this point, I do not know how to continue solving the exercise. I have tried with a binomial distribution of parameter 6 but its formula is B (n, p), which I think I only have p. Is it well done? How can I continue solving it?

For section 2, once I have the previous distribution, I have to calculate that Pr {X> 2} Is it correct?

Comment: Usually, when I had given mean and standard deviation I use a normal distribution. Anyway, whichever you choose, the $p$ for the binomial distribution is $P(S<4200)$ where $S$ is the sales random variable so circa $0.55$, with your values. The $n$ for the binomial is the number of months: $6$.

Comment: @N74 So for section 1 you would have to do B (6, s <4200). But I do not understand where that 0.55 is coming from and how to calculate this distribution without integers

Comment: If you don't want to use integrals, for an uninform distribution, and using your notation, $p=(4200-a)/(b-a)$

Comment: @N74 What I did was that for there to be losses in one period, it has to be v <4200. I calculate Pr (v <4200) which is the integral between 1921.539030 and 4200 and gives me result of 0.5481. Then I calculate the binomial B (6, 
 0.04881) and Pr (x> = 3) = Pr(x> 2) = 0.741584 on the binomial and would it be fine?

Comment: Why $0.04881$ instead of $0.5481$?

Comment: @N74 Sorry, it's B(6 , 0.5481) I got confused when transcribing it here, so I think that was the only mistake and the result seems correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that "distributed evenly" means uniformly. Let $S$ be the number of sales in a given month.

$$S \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(a,b)$$

Then we know $E[S] = \dfrac{1}{2}(a+b)$ and $Var(S) = \dfrac{1}{12}(b-a)^2$. Solving for $a,b$ when $E[S] = 4000$ and $Var[S] = 1200^2$ yields $a=1921.539030, b = 6078.46096$ (with one extraneous solution).

In any given month, with fixed cost $4200$, the probability of a loss is
$$P(S \leq 4200)$$

Once you have found that, let $X$ be number of losses in six months.

$$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(6, P(S \leq 4200))$$

Then you want to find $P(X \geq 3)$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I just did not know if what I had done was fine up to this point. I tried to continue but I do not know, it's the first time I work with intervals in p

Comment: @Fernando Do you mean you need help understanding $P(S \leq 4200)$?

Comment: What I did was that for there to be losses in one period, it has to be v <4200. I calculate Pr (v <4200) which is the integral between 1921.539030 and 4200 and gives me result of 0.5481. Then I calculate the binomial B (6.0.04881) and Pr (x> = 3) = Prx> 2) = 0.741584 on the binomial and would it be fine?

Comment: @Fernando Where are you getting 0.0488 from?

Comment: Sorry, it's B(6 , 0.5481) I got confused when transcribing it here, so I think that was the only mistake and the result seems correct